# Awk and double quoting

Tags: file, date, awk, sed

I need some help with awk and double quoting.
I have this text file with separated by tab values (multiple lines).

Ex.

> 22-03-2016 11:25   25  Session reconnection succeeded  user    10.10.10.10

Now I want to change the date notation.
I want above example to be 
2016-03-22 11:25  (as in `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M`)

I am trying to use awk (on my mac) 
I manually can change the date with:

```
date -j -u -f "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M" "22-03-2016 11:25" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

result: 2016-03-22 11:25

I am struggling with awk to do this. Having problems with the quoting.

Any other ways of doing this are appreciated!

Regards,

Ronald

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So I found a solution using sed.. (had to switch to a real linux enviroment.. but ok)

Using this command:
sed -i.bak -r 's/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\3-\2-\1/g' TextFile

Always funny how I find the answer right after I post a question....